# Grabbing current list item in infopath with C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, infopath

I am trying to grab the current list item, which is an infopath form. So far I am connecting to the sharepoint site, opening the list and trying to grab the current item, but I keep getting an index out of range error. Here is my code

```
            SPSite WebApp = new SPSite("http://site/");
            SPWeb site = WebApp.OpenWeb();
            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPList list = Site.Lists.TryGetList("List_Library");

            WebApp.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            SPListItem item = list.Items[list.Items.Count];
```

My question is how can I grab the current list? This code is located in the code behind for the infopath form and is in the FormEvents_Submit method that is called when the Submit event is fired. I tried moving the code to the bottom of the method to ensure that the form gets submitted first, but was still receiving the out of range error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was trying to access the list item BEFORE the InfoPath form was submitted, so it didn't exist in the list yet. To get around this, I would have to put my code at the end of the Form_Submit event and make sure the list.Update() was finished before trying to grab the item.

Answer (score 1):

the list item is zero based index: Count-1

Answer (score 0):

Side note: Is it server form (Forms Server) or client? If it is client form you should not be using SharePoint server side OM unless your form will **always** run on the server.

FormEvents_Submit should handle submission of the form completely. So it is responsibility of your code to save item first in whatever way you need. Generally as result of saving an object you get back some idenity that you can use to retrive it back (i.e. SPList.AddItem already returns you SPListItem)

Comment: How do I add the current item using AddItem? I am having trouble locating the object that represents the current item. I believe it is a client form.

Comment: InfoPath itself does not have concept of "current item", so it is hard to advice something. If you figure out what identifies "current item" in your case it would be possible to suggest ways of getting it from SharePoint. NOTE: as I've mentioned if the form runs in InfoPath client than using server side SharePoint OM is likely wrong: use web services or client side OM (new in 2010).